# APFS Volume encryption failed to begin (-69596) -- Solved

Tags: encryption, filevault

So I have a problem to encrypt an external Thunderbolt-HDD which was converted to APFS.  Catalina is installed on that iMac late 2012.  First I've tried to encrypt the volume in the Finder via context menu; an internal error (without number) was reported.  The I've tried the Terminal:

```
iForst:~ michaelhoppe$ diskutil apfsencryptVolume disk5s2 -user disk
Passphrase for the new "Disk" user (...):

  Repeat passphrase:

Starting background encryption with the new "Disk" crypto user on disk5s2

The new "Disk" user will be the only one who has initial access to  disk5s2

The new APFS crypto user UUID will be ...

Error starting encryption of APFS Volume: APFS Volume encryption failed to begin (-69596)
```

What's happening here?  Couldn't find something about the -69596 on the Internet.

EDIT: Finally found a solution: After a repartition of the HDD with a slightly different size I was able to encrypt the disk.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately -- for me, some APFS volumes in the same partition would encrypt fine but the majority of volumes failed with this message. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: BTW, "slightly different size" is ambiguous, so I tried shrinking it by 100GB, which didn't work, and then re-sizing it back to the original size and that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but it works for me, at least.  It was a 10TB HDD partitioned into 4 + 6 TB.  Still works (fingers crossed ;).